# How to read user input after flags

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that downloads and compiles a program and I don't know what i should be looking up to accomplish what I want, so here I go...

What I want:

```
sudo pacstall -I program
```

What it does now

```
sudo pacstall -I
```

then I would  type in program to install program.

So how do I get it to 'ask for input' after typing in the -I flag (I for install)? I'm very new to bash scripting so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash) answer your question?

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Like I said, i'm new to bash scripting and all I want to to combine pacstall -I and the next line, which asks for user input, into one line. Just like pacman, but in bash

Comment: You have to read user input before you issue that command. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544359/how-to-read-user-input-into-a-variable-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this a year later, this was a pretty stupid question. The answer is positional variables, like `$1`, `$2`, etc

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n 'Enter the package name: '
read package
test -n "$package" && sudo pacstall -I "$package"
```